# Xamarin - how to receive iMessage/SMS in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, notifications, imessage

Is is possible to receive iMessage/SMS on iOS using Xamarin? Or at least notification that iMessage/SMS was received?

For Android there is Android.Content.BroadcastReceiver class but I can't find similar for iOS.

Comment: Short answer: No

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover  Not even possible to receive information that iMessage/SMS was received?

Comment: No. Without being able to access the details of the SMS (which Apple doesn't want), that wouldn't be a very useful API to have.

Comment: So if I want to sent from my app to wearable device (like smartwatch) notification that SMS was received I won't be able to do this on iOS? :(